# How do I enter UserAgentMetadata into the driver to change the header?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I want to change user information in chrome selenium header in c# language.
I wrote this code after a lot of searching, but I don't know how to enter the UserAgentMetadata into the driver.
Please help in C# code language.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V109.Emulation;

namespace web_traffic
{
    internal class DevTraffic
    {
        ChromeDriver driver;
        string path = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
        public void setysermeta()
        {
            string Url = "https://whatismyipaddress.com/";
            ChromeOptions ChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            UserAgentMetadata agentMetadata = new UserAgentMetadata();
            agentMetadata.Mobile = true;
            agentMetadata.Platform = "Android";
            agentMetadata.Architecture = "x86"; 
            //ChromeOptions.EnableMobileEmulation( agentMetadata);
            ChromeOptions.AddArgument($"{agentMetadata}");
            
            driver= new ChromeDriver(ChromeOptions);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);
            

        }
    }
}
```